# Asp.Net MVC: Current User changes after Registration of a new user

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am having a problem with my asp.net application. I am using the default Register.aspx to register a new user. After the user have been successfully created i am redirected to a new page that informs me of the success. When i try to navigate to a different page the current user changes to the one i just created. I want to keep the current user. What am i missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Remove the following line from your `Register` action in the `Account` controller upon successful registration:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false);
```

This is what changes the user by emitting a new authentication cookie in the response with this username.

Comment: @joy84, if this post helped you solve the problem you were having you should consider [marking it as answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking no the tick next to it.